# Is it possible to convert pixel coordinates of an image to lat,long using GDAL in C++?

Tags: c++, gdal

The image I have is a georeferenced tiff image which has a reference frame of EPSG 4326. I have a set of points which i need to convert to lat and long. I am using Visual Studio along with GDAL 2.3.1 for my project. I am unable to get the C++ equivalent of the below which is in python:

```
"trans = gdal.transformer(image, None [])
success,xyz=trans.TransformPoint(0,Posx,Posy)
lat=xyz[0]
long=xyz[1]
"
```

The contents inside my main is shown below:

```
GDALAllRegister();
    GDALDataset* data = (GDALDataset*) GDALOpen(filename,GA_ReadOnly);
    OGRSpatialReference source,target;
    source.importFromEPSG(4326);
    target.importFromEPSG(4326);
    //setting my pixels here for pixel location(500,500)
    OGRPoint p; 
    p.setX(500); 
    p.setY(500); 
    p.assignSpatialReference(&source);
    p.transformTo(&target);
    // transformed coordinates 
    cout << p.getX() << " | " << p.getY();
```

I started out by using the sample code in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49888551/), which gave me the same result of lat,long as my pixel location. How is that possible? Is the any function in the GDAL library for converting the pixel coordinates to Lat and Long in EPSG 4326. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your code. Did you check this https://gdal.org/api/index.html#id3?

Answer (score 0):

I use the node-gdal library to do the same stuff. You can follow the example at https://github.com/naturalatlas/node-gdal/blob/master/examples/gdalinfo.js to see how they convert a pixel to lat/lon coordinates.

Comment: Thank you but, i was looking for something in C++. I have added the minimal reproducible example of the code.